# Embed pdf in .ejs file

Tags: node.js, express, pdf, ejs

I have a web app using `express.js` and I've tried to embed a `pdf` into a `.ejs` file as follows:

```
embed src="mypdf.pdf" width="500" height="375" />
```

This gives me the following error when I load that page: `Cannot GET /mypdf.pdf`

What is the correct way to display a pdf embedded in an `.ejs` file using `express.js` (I only want the pdf to take up a portion of the page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the correct path for your pdf.

Check the similar line in your app.js

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Here `public` is the directory which you are telling express to consider for [static resources](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) and can be accessed directly with root path.

Now create a new folder in this `public` folder called docs or you can put pdf directly in the `public` folder

change embed tag as following

```
<embed src="/doc/mypdf.pdf" width="500" height="375" type="application/pdf">
```

if you put pdf directly in a public folder then change the path to `/mypdf.pdf`.

Comment: Thank you that works now. Is there a way to allow the pdf to go fullscreen if it is clicked on?

Comment: Create a button separately to trigger full screen, find your element by id and replace the heigh and width property. This is also deprecated tag use <object> instead.

A potential solution would be to open the pdf in a separate window from your site with a target="_blank" attribute on a tag so that the pdf can be viewed in full-screen mode and fill up the entire screen.